# Sequelize JS Insert Error

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I created a [sequelize raw query](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html) helper function that will insert data from my mysql database.

```
const addBudget = function(name, amount) {
  sequelize.query(
    'INSERT INTO budget (name, amount) VALUES(' + name + ',' + amount + ')', {
      type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT
    }
  ).then(function (data) {
    console.log('inserted STEAMER data---> ', data);     });
};
```

And then when I call the function to try to insert some data on mysql database to see if it's inserting the my data to the record:

```
addBudget('Book', 100);
```

I got this error:

```
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): INSERT INTO budget (name, amount) VALUES(Book,100)
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'Book' in 'field list'
    at Query.formatError (/Users/mac/Documents/dudes/moira/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:247:16)
    at Query.handler [as onResult] (/Users/mac/Documents/dudes/moira/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:68:23)
    at Query.Command.execute (/Users/mac/Documents/dudes/moira/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:30:12)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/mac/Documents/dudes/moira/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:502:28)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/mac/Documents/dudes/moira/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:81:16)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/mac/Documents/dudes/moira/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:77:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/Documents/dudes/moira/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:89:29)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:581:20)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here when it comes to inserting data to the database?

Comment: I think you are quoting the string 'Book' again inside your query, try removing it. It should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here is your values should be covered b/w single quote or double quote , but with your code it generates `VALUES(Book,100);` , that should be `VALUES('Book','100');` , For that

Just change below line :

```
'INSERT INTO budget (name, amount) VALUES(' + name + ',' + amount + ')'
```

With this :

```
`INSERT INTO budget (name, amount) VALUES('${name}','${amount}')`
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL only allows single-quote strings for your values. So, this will not work:

```
'INSERT INTO budget (name, amount) VALUES("Book", 100)'
```

Nor will this:

```
'INSERT INTO budget (name, amount) VALUES(Book, 100)'
```

Assuming you instructed SQL to read the amount as an integer, this is the proper way to insert your values:

```
'INSERT INTO budget (name, amount) VALUES('Book', 100)'
```

If Book is just a variable that is already a string, you can also do this to insure the single-quote rule is kept:

```
`INSERT INTO budget (name, amount) VALUES('${Book}', 100)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
var sql = "insert into budget (name) values ()";
sequelize.execute(sql, function(error, result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

execute insert and update sql and get more informations